# If else Jquery for IP number

Tags: jquery, ip

I'm trying to test to see if my IP number matches with the one specified. I'm new to Javascript, and not sue what's wrong with my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var userIP = (data.ip);
    var myIP = 172.16.254.1;

    if (userIP == myIP) {
      $("body").html("<p>IP Login Success!</p>");
    } else {
      $("body").html("<p>Invalid IP!</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make it see if the IP matches the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var myIP = "172.16.254.1";
```

You are assigning a literal string to myIP.